# RHEL 6.5 won't boot after loading APF firewall

Tags: rhel, iptables

We have an RHEL 6.5 system which boots to the point of loading APF firewall and then just hangs indefinitely. The console shows the following:

```
...
Loading autofs4: [OK]
Starting automount: [OK]
Starting SWsoft control panels server... [OK]
Starting APF: ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
```

[image]

It then waits indefinitely on the screen above.  The only way we have been able to work around this was to disable the APF service from starting at boot.

/var/log/messages shows the following:

```
May  9 04:15:29 sapphire acpid: waiting for events: event logging is off
May  9 04:15:29 sapphire acpid: client connected from 6777[68:68]
May  9 04:15:29 sapphire acpid: 1 client rule loaded
May  9 04:15:30 sapphire automount[6797]: lookup_read_master: lookup(nisplus): couldn't locate nis+ table auto.master
May  9 04:15:31 sapphire kernel: ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
May  9 04:15:31 sapphire kernel: nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
```

/var/log/apf_log consistently shows the following as the last lines before boot hangs:

```
May 09 04:15:33 server apf(6915): {dshield} downloading http://feeds.dshield.org/top10-2.txt
May 09 04:15:33 server apf(6915): {dshield} parsing top10-2.txt into /etc/apf/ds_hosts.rules
May 09 04:15:33 server apf(6915): {dshield} loading ds_hosts.rules

May 09 04:30:50 server apf(2681): {dshield} downloading http://feeds.dshield.org/top10-2.txt
May 09 04:30:51 server apf(2681): {dshield} parsing top10-2.txt into /etc/apf/ds_hosts.rules
May 09 04:30:51 server apf(2681): {dshield} loading ds_hosts.rules

May 09 04:48:45 server apf(2653): {dshield} downloading http://feeds.dshield.org/top10-2.txt
May 09 04:48:46 server apf(2653): {dshield} parsing top10-2.txt into /etc/apf/ds_hosts.rules
May 09 04:48:46 server apf(2653): {dshield} loading ds_hosts.rules
```

So it would seem that loading of the DShield rules is causing boot to hang.

After successfully booting, both iptables and APF are running fine.

Can anyone suggest how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What does `/var/log/messages` say for the failed boots? You may also want to `SET_VERBOSE` recreate the issue and check `/var/log/apf_log`

Comment: Added info from /var/log/messages to original question - nothing particularly obvious there. How do we do `SET_VERBOSE`?

Comment: It's a configuration option. [See Section 3.1](https://www.rfxn.com/appdocs/README.apf)

Comment: Just checked and `SET_VERBOSE` is already enabled in `/etc/apf/conf.apf` so that isn't the problem. It looks as if nf_conntrack is causing the problem as it's the last line in the logs...

Comment: Last in both logs? Also, it could have just been the last thing to succeed. Looking at your messages output, do you use automount? Might a required directory not be mount until after boot time?

Comment: Added info from `/var/log/apf_log` to original question. Seems DShield rules were causing boot to hang. Today we tried a reboot and everything worked fine so something must have been up with the parsing/loading of DShield rules yesterday...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to have fixed itself as rebooting with the same configuration now works fine. As the system boot was hanging when loading the dynamically downloaded `ds_hosts.rules` file from DShield, we can only assume that there was a problem with this file which has since been updated as nothing else has changed on the system.

The temporary workaround, while the server would not boot, was to disable APF at startup by booting in to single-user mode and then running:

`chkconfig apf off`